# Counting with permutations and counting ignoring permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am given this problem:

This problem was given to me in my computer science class but it has to do with permutation and I want to understand it mathematically first.

let $c(n)$ be the number of different group integers that can be chosen from the integers $1$ through $n-1$, so that the integers in each group add up to n (for example, $n=4=[1+1+1+1]=[1+1+2]=[2+2]$). Write a recursive definition for $c(n)$ under the following variations:

a) You count permutations. For example, $1,2,1$ and $1,1,2$ are two groups that each add up to $4$

b)you ignore permutations

I know permutations is how many ways you can arrange a set of numbers But what am I counting when I ignore permutations?

Comment: When you ignore order, you get what are called the **partitions** of $n$.  Counting partitions is a complicated problem. There are useful recurrences. Please see the article on partitions in Wikipedia. When we take order into account, we get the **compositions** of $n$. These are much easier to count than partitions.

Comment: ok, so in the article's example they use $4$ and they say $p(4)=5$ because  they count $4$ but here I have the constraint $1$ to $n-1$ so there for my answer would be $3$ correct?

Comment: Yes, your function is $p(n)-1$, a very close relative of $p(n)$. The same remark applies to compositions. Note that $n$ has $2^{n-1}$ compositions, so your function for order counts is $2^{n-1}-1$.

Comment: I meant the answer should be $4$ for $p(4)$

Comment: $p(4)=5$, for the partitions are $4$, $3+1$, $2+2$, $2+1+1$, and $1+1+1+1$. So your $c(4)=4$. In general your $c(n)$ is $p(n)-1$.